# Python: Conversion from dictionary to array

Tags: python, arrays

I have a Python dictionary (say **D**) where every key corresponds to some predefined list. I want to create an array with two columns where the **first column corresponds to the keys** of the dictionary D and the **second column corresponds to the sum of the elements in the corresponding lists**. As an example, if,

```
D = {1: [5,55], 2: [25,512], 3: [2, 18]}
```

Then, the array that I wish to create should be,

```
A = array( [[1,60], [2,537], [3, 20]] )
```

I have given a small example here, but I would like to know of a way where the implementation is the **fastest**. Presently, I am using the following method:

```
A_List = map( lambda x: [x,sum(D[x])] , D.keys() )
```

I realize that the output from my method is in the form of a list. I can convert it into an array in another step, but I don't know if that will be a fast method (I presume that the use of arrays will be faster than the use of lists). I will really appreciate an answer where I can know what's the **fastest way** of achieving this aim.

Comment: You can shave 5% or so off by replacing lists with tuples: `(x,sum(D[x]))`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension to create the desired output:

```
>>> [(k, sum(v)) for k, v in D.items()]   # Py2 use D.iteritems()
[(1, 60), (2, 537), (3, 20)]
```

On my computer, this runs about 50% quicker than the `map(lambda:.., D)` version.
Note: On py3 `map` just returns a generator so you need to `list(map(...))` to get the real time it takes.

Comment: There's a definite improvement in time. I notice a 40% in time which is significant when I run the code for big datasets. Thanks! =)

Answer (score 2):

I hope that helps:

1. Build an array with the values of the keys of D:

   ```
   first_column = list(D.keys())
   ```
2. Build an array with the sum of values in each key:

   ```
   second_column = [sum(D[key]) for key in D.keys()]
   ```
3. Build an array with shape [first_column,second_column]

   ```
   your_array = list(zip(first_column,second_column))
   ```

Comment: From the way you have defined it, ' your_array ', turns out to be a list. I hope I am not missing anything here.

Comment: Yes, that's because D elements are not (let's say) numpy arrays. We could cast `numpy.array(your_array)` if needed.

Comment: Just saw, np.array(your_array) gives two rows. It will be best if I could have it in two column form. ( np.array(your_array) ).reshape( len(first_column), 2) messes the format up. For the I would like, A = array( [[1,60], [2,537], [3, 20]] ).

Comment: Hmm, I can use np.swapaxes( np.array(your_array) ), 0, 1 )  to get around this. =)

Answer (score 2):

You can try this also:

```
a=[]
for i in D.keys():
  a+=[[i,sum(D[i])]]
```